# validate message not showing to user anywhere on the screen

Tags: r, shiny

My dataframe train_df gets filtered for the inputs that the user provides. After that I use the filtered datframe to run a model. But if user sets the filter too narrow,and there are no points for those filters, I want to show an error message to the user preferably in a modal box(if not then anywhere) that there are no points found for your filters. I use the following code on my server side. 'update' is the input id of my button in the UI
})

```
observeEvent(input$update,{


shiny::validate(
        need(nrow(train_df) > 0, "No points found for these filters!")
      )
    
})
```

My validate statement works but the error message does not show up in the app. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hard to diagnose the problem without even looking at the full code showing how `train_df` was created.

Comment: I believe `validate` shows its message in the UI element in which the code is included (either directly or via reactive dependency). Here, you aren't including it in anything UI-related, so it doesn't have anywhere to go. For instance, if you have `data <- reactive({ validate(...); ...})` and then elsewhere `output$tbl <- renderTable({ data(); })`, then the validate message will display in the `"tbl"` UI element.

Comment: See https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/validation.html and https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/validate.html